# Image Cropping tool for PHP website

Tags: php

I want to embed the cropping tool into my php based website.
This cropping too should have the option to zoom in, drag from left to right or right to left and the can crop the image. I've embedded the cropping tool of croopic.net to my page and can be seen here http://www.furniturenation.com/croppic/. But it is failed to crop large images.

Do some body know about such cropping tool. 
Paid or Free both will be appreciated.